# JQGrid, Edit Url

Tags: jqgrid

I  am new to jQuery, and I need to use jqGrid in my project.

I have one problem with edit/delete/insert; I have only one URL, `editurl`, then in the controller I am using the `oper` property to decide whether it is an insert or delete operation.

But I want to have a separate URL for the edit, delete and insert operations in jqGrid. Could you please let me know how to achieve that?

Client side code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastsel2;
    var grid = jQuery("#list5").jqGrid({
        url: '/home1/GetUserData',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        colNames: ['Code', 'LoginID', 'Emailid', 'CreateDate'],
        colModel: [
        // { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 75, sortable: false },
                        {name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 55, editable: true },
                        { name: 'LoginID', index: 'LoginID', width: 90, editable: true },
                        { name: 'Emailid', index: 'Emailid', width: 100, editable: true },
                    { name: 'CreateDate', index: 'CreateDate', width: 100, editable: true }
                      ],
        rowNum: 10,
        width: 700,
        height: 300,
        rowList: 10,
        pager: $("#pager2"),
        editurl: "/home1/EditUserData",
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel2) {
                if (id == "new_row") {
                    grid.setGridParam({ editurl: "/home1/InsertUserData" });
                }
                else {
                    grid.setGridParam({ editurl: "/home1/EditUserData" });
                }
                jQuery('#list5').restoreRow(lastsel2);
                $("#list5_ilsave").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                $("#list5_ilcancel").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                $("#list5_iladd").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                $("#list5_iledit").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                lastsel2 = id;
            }
        },
        caption: "Simple data manipulation"
    });
    jQuery("#list5").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: false }, {}, {}, { url: '/home1/DeleteUserData' });
    jQuery("#list5").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#pager2", { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass options for all the actions with navGrid method like this:

```
jQuery('#list5').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: true, add: true, del: true },
    //edit options
    { url: '/home1/EditUserData' },
    //add options
    { url: '/home1/AddUserData' },
    //delete options
    { url: '/home1/DeleteUserData' }
);
```

Please read more [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing).

**UPDATE**

In case of inlineNav method jqGrid is always passing the same set of parameters ([editParams](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing)) to saveRow method. As the effect the edit/add request will be made to the same URL. You are sticked with checking `oper` to distinguish edit for add.

In the subject of reloading the grid you can use editParams to set aftersavefunc to trigger `realoadGrid` like this:

```
jQuery('#list5').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager2', { edit: true, add: true, editParams: {
   aftersavefunc: function(rowId, response) { jQuery('#list5').trigger('reloadGrid'); }
}});
```

But you should remember that it will also cause a refresh after edit (because of the same reason as described above) - you may try to use response parameter to distinguish those two. I have also removed del, search and refresh from the code as inlineNav doesn't have those options.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is working for FORM EDITING not for INLINE EDITING, and i want for inline editing.

Comment: @Meraj Well your sample code is using navGrid (which is using form editing settings). Nothing in your question suggests that you are using inline editing. Please update your code so I can see how you are using inline editing so I can help you.

Comment: Extremely very sorry, i updated my code, so please check it and let me know where i am wrong, now using above code, somehow, i am getting different URL for Edit/Update/Delete, but again one problem is, i am not able to reload the grid after ADDING NEW RECORD.

Comment: @tpeczek thanks for ur response, with this i got the solution what i want, But please let me know the way i am doing is right or wrong if its wrong then i will try the better way to solve my problem.

Comment: @tpeczek, As you suggested that, to distinguish between Add and Edit, i may use Response parameter, but if i use "rowId" i can easily distinguish between two becoz for Add operation it the "rowId" value will always be "new_row".

Comment: @Meraj You are right, rowId is perfectly fine in this situation.